# Basic makefile for arduino using avr-gcc

Tags: makefile, arduino, avr, arduino-uno, avr-gcc

I would like to make a makefile for compiling c programs for the arduino. I am somewhat familiar with make but have never used it with avr-gcc. What is the simplest way I could put the commands below in a makefile?

```
$ avr-gcc -Os -DF_CPU=16000000UL -mmcu=atmega328p -c -o led.o led.c
$ avr-gcc -mmcu=atmega328p led.o -o led
$ avr-objcopy -O ihex -R .eeprom led led.hex
$ avrdude -F -V -c arduino -p ATMEGA328P -P /dev/ttyACM0 -b 115200 -U flash:w:led.hex
```

Comment: For those of us not familiar with avr-gcc, could you tell us what the third and fourth commands do?

Comment: third one makes a hex file for flashing and fourth does the flashing

Comment: as in writing to the flash memory on the mcu

Answer (score 2):

The simple-as-a-meataxe way is just to wrap the commands in a recipe:

```
.PHONY: all
all:
    avr-gcc -Os -DF_CPU=16000000UL -mmcu=atmega328p -c -o led.o led.c
    avr-gcc -mmcu=atmega328p led.o -o led
    avr-objcopy -O ihex -R .eeprom led led.hex
    avrdude -F -V -c arduino -p ATMEGA328P -P /dev/ttyACM0 -b 115200 -U flash:w:led.hex
```

Just type `make`, and it will run. It works, but it's just a dumb script. A better way is by wrapping each command in a rule, with correct names and prerequisites:

```
# I still don't know what this one does. ("flashing"?)
.PHONY: flash
flash: led.hex
    avrdude -F -V -c arduino -p ATMEGA328P -P /dev/ttyACM0 -b 115200 -U flash:w:led.hex

led.o: led.c
    avr-gcc -Os -DF_CPU=16000000UL -mmcu=atmega328p -c -o led.o led.c

led: led.o
    avr-gcc -mmcu=atmega328p led.o -o led

led.hex: led
    avr-objcopy -O ihex -R .eeprom led led.hex
```

That will prevent a lot of unnecessary work, such as rebuilding `led` and `led.o` when they're already up to date. We can improve it further by making some of these rules into pattern rules, so that later if you want to add `servo.c` to the project you won't have to write new versions of everything:

```
# Can other things "flash"? Or be "flashed"? The word has several definitions.
.PHONY: flash
flash: led.hex
    avrdude -F -V -c arduino -p ATMEGA328P -P /dev/ttyACM0 -b 115200 -U flash:w:led.hex

%.o: %.c
    avr-gcc -Os -DF_CPU=16000000UL -mmcu=atmega328p -c -o $@ $<

%: %.o
    avr-gcc -mmcu=atmega328p $< -o $@

%.hex: %
    avr-objcopy -O ihex -R .eeprom $< $@
```

Further improvements are possible, but a lot depends on how you intend to use this makefile and in which directions you intend to expand the project.